# Terraform: Output a field from a module

Tags: terraform

## Code

Consider a terraform module:

```
module "blah-asg" {
  source = "asg"

  asg_max_size       = 1
  asg_min_size       = "${var.min_blah}"
  ...
}
```

## My problem

How do I [`output`](https://www.terraform.io/intro/getting-started/outputs.html) variables from it?

## What have I tried

```
output "blah-es-asg" {
    value = "${asg.blah-asg.arn}"
}
```

Which failed with

> Error getting plugins: module root: 1 error(s) occurred:
>   * output 'blah-asg': unknown resource 'asg.blah' referenced in variable asg.blah-asg.arn

## My question

How can I output module fields in Terraform?

Comment: Please consider accepting the post that addresses/ed your issue (just a friendly reminder).

Answer (score 80):

So first, you need to set the output in the module `asg`:

```
$ cat asg/output.tf

output "blah-es-asg" {
    value = "${aws_autoscaling_group.blah-asg.arn}"
}
```

Then you call the module with `source = "asg"`:

```
module "blah-asg" {
  source = "asg"

  asg_max_size       = 1
  asg_min_size       = "${var.min_blah}"
  ...
}
```

You can output it in current code with this format now:

```
output "blah-es-asg" {
    value = "${module.blah-asg.blah-es-asg}"
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, should have been an accepted answer.

Comment: s helpful with the explanation and walk-thru you gave. it would of been more clear if the original poster would of used better things than blah and so on. it took me a minute to convert real life.. but thanks for help others out there!!!

Comment: I wish the terraform docs had this answer/example. Ty

Comment: But is it necessary to be two steps ? one outputs.tf in module, then another outputs on main ?

Comment: fantastic, `${module.blah-asg.blah-es-asg}` worked for me !!!

Answer (score 7):

The module itself knows nothing of the name `blah-asg` - that's just in the script that's calling it - indeed it could be called multiple times with different names and parameters.

The output should just reference things within the module the same way you would elsewhere in that same module.  For instance, if you wanted to output the arn of the following resource:

```
resource "aws_lb" "test" {
  # ...
}
```

You would use:

```
output "blah-es-asg" {
    value = "${aws_lb.test.arn}"
}
```

Note that the output is defined along side the rest of the module code, not in the script that's calling it.

This output can then by used by the script calling the module as `${module.blah-asg.blah-es-asg}`

Answer (score 3):

Say your module looks like this in your main.tf file:

```
module "vpc" {
  source = "terraform-aws-modules/vpc/aws"
```

Your output can be accessed this way in outputs.tf file

```
output "vpc_id" {
value = module.vpc.vpc_id
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use module.[module-name].[output-variable-name]

e.g. in Azure for create a resource_group with the name og the module output

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "my-test-rg" {
     name =  module.blah-asg.blah-es-asg  
}
```