# How to get the Data like name of the resource from a Module or terraform file which is in a different directory?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

How to get the data from module which is in a different directory.
I have a Directory called `modules` under this directory i have two subdirectories called `template` and `instance-from-template`. In `template` directory I have all the files to create a Instance template in GCP and I am successfully able to create a template from it. Now I want to utilize the name of the template in another directory `instance-from-template` where I am trying create an instance from the existing template. But if I use module and mention my source as `modules/template` it is asking me the variables to create a new template. But I want to use the existing one.

I have used `outputs.tf` and used module in instance from template assuming that it might help me to get the parameters. And trying to use something like this

```
source_instance_template = "${module.template.template-name}"
```

code in modules->template->main.tf

```
  resource "google_compute_instance_template" "appserver" {
  name        = "${var.templatename}"
  description = "This template is used to create app server instances."

  tags = ["terraform-gcp", "test"]

  labels = {
    environment = "${var.env}"
  }

  instance_description = "${var.description}"
  machine_type         = "${var.machinetype}"
  can_ip_forward       = false

  scheduling {
    automatic_restart   = true
    on_host_maintenance = "MIGRATE"
  }

  // Create a new boot disk from an image
  disk {
    source_image = "${var.templateimage}"
    auto_delete  = "${var.autodelete}"
    boot         = true
  }

  // Use an existing disk resource

  network_interface {
    network = "${var.templatenetwork}"
  }

  metadata = {
    foo = "bar"
  }

  service_account {
    email =  "${var.serviceemail}"
    scopes = ["compute-ro", "storage-ro"]
  }
    lifecycle {
    create_before_destroy = true
  }
}

output "template-name"{
    value = "${google_compute_instance_template.appserver.name}"
}
```

Code in modules->instance-from-template->main.tf

```
module template{
    source="../template"
}
resource "google_compute_instance_from_template" "tpl" {
  name           = "instance-from1-template"
  zone           = "us-central1-a"

  source_instance_template = "${module.template.template-name}"

  // Override fields from instance template
  can_ip_forward = false
  labels = {
    my_key       = "my_value_test"
  }
}
```

error

```
    on instance-from-template.tf line 1, in module "template":
   1: module template{

The argument "templatename" is required, but no definition was found.
```

Comment: you can check how to use output directive to export variables from one module to another, this is documented in the terraform docs

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Terraform: Output a field from a module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47034515/terraform-output-a-field-from-a-module)