# Terraform unable to feed for_each output into another module

Tags: google-cloud-platform, terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

Ideally, I originally wanted to output a list of `self_link` for GCP in my terraform output, but can't even get a simple string to work:

```
module "master-nodes" {
  source          = "./master-nodes"
  network         = google_compute_network.k3s.self_link
  project         = var.project
  service_account = var.service_account
  ssh             = var.ssh

  for_each     = var.servers
  name         = each.key
  subnet_name  = each.key
  region       = each.value.region
  cidr_range   = each.value.cidr_range
  machine_type = each.value.machine_type
}

module "networking" {
  source    = "./networking"
  network   = google_compute_network.k3s.self_link
  instance_names = module.master-nodes.instance_names[*].name
}
```

I want to feed `instance_names` into the `networking` module after the compute resources have been created. Inside my `master-nodes` modules, I have outputs defined like so:

```
output "instance_names" {
  value = google_compute_instance.k3s-master.name
  description = "The names of the instances created by the master-nodes module."
}
```

I've tried many variations of this:

```
output "instance_names" {
  value = [ for compute in google_compute_instance.k3s-master.name: compute.name]
  description = "The names of the instances created by the master-nodes module."
}


output "instance_names" {
  value = [for instance in module.master-nodes : instance.name]
  description = "The names of the instances created by the master-nodes module."
}
```

Nothing works. How should I set this up?

Comment: Please update the question with information describing the current versus desired behavior.

Answer (score 0):

The docs about output is not so clear. There are some questions related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61587712/cannot-get-the-outputs-when-terraform-output-is-run).

First you need to create this output file in the same place you ran `terraform apply`. For your case:

```
output "instance_names" {
  value = [for instance in module.master-nodes : instance.name]
  description = "The names of the instances created by the master-nodes module."
}
```

This syntax should works, since your **master-nodes** are exporting the variable **name**.

PS: Remember to run `terraform apply` to generate the outputs.